# Are thermal fuses polarized?

Tags: fuses, thermal

I have a device with a thermal fuse in it. The fuse has failed, and I would like to replace it.

Does thermal fuse have a polarity, similar to an electrolytic capacitor, or is it the same with normal fuse? It has a stripe marking on it.

Is it sensitive to polarization, or will either way work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short:**  No. Thermal fuses are not polarised.

---

**Longer :-) :**

No thermal fuse I have ever seen was polarised (based on decades of experience but ...).

I cannot think why a thermal fuse would be polarised.

This seems to be extremely unlikely but I mention it for completeness:
 **If** a device that was **called** a thermal fuse WAS polarised then it would be more than a fuse - it would be very special in some unusual manner.
 If so then it would need to be replaced by an identical unit if it was going to do the same job.

---

A photo would be a good idea.
 Does it have a part number on it?

Comment: i can't see the part number, blew up already...but the mark there ( label ) is fuse..

Comment: But can someone tell me why KiCad have a symbol labelled 'Fuse_Polarized' with a red band near one terminal of the fuse symbol?